# При парсинге сайта выводится None

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Решил написать парсер который собирает все теги  из HTML-кода сайта: news.google.com и сохраняет их в .txt файл
Но, при запуске программы мне выводит None.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Scraper:
    def __init__(self, site):
        self.site = site

    def scrape(self):
        r = urllib.request.urlopen(self.site)
        html = r.read()
        parser = "html.parser"
        sp = BeautifulSoup(html, parser)
        for tag in sp.find_all("link"):
            url = tag.get("href")
            if url is None:
                continue
            if "html" in url:
                print("\n" + url)

news = "https://news.google.com/topstories?hl=ru&gl=RU&ceid=RU:ru"
a = Scraper(news).scrape()
print(a)

f = open("news.txt", "w")
f.write(Scraper(news).scrape())
f.close()
```

Comment: Предположу, что контент страницы наполняется при помощи ajax средствами javascript. В этом случае bs4 бесполезен. Вам нужно смотреть в сторону управления браузером (например selenium), а не парсинга статичных html-файлов

Comment: @cauf Спасибо большое, есть смысл пробовать другие сайты, или сейчас везде таким способом наполняется контент страницы?

Comment: Попробовать - смысл есть. Но найти сайт, отдающи статичные страницы с контентом все сложнее. Если исключительно в образовательных целях, то попробуйте поискать какие-то старые сайты с минимум интерактивности

Comment: Я создал HTML файл  с тэгом <a></a> который при нажатии открывает google.com и открыл его с помощью локального сервера. Ввел туда в коде ссылку "test.ru"(я так назвал домен), и все-равно выводит None. Может ошибка в коде, сможете подсказать пожалуйста?

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Если вы создали какой-то статичный html-файл, то выложите его код (например на  pastebin) и дайте ссылку.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/2w2g6eFq - код на пайтоне
https://pastebin.com/Y1guizU6 - HTML - код

Comment: Вы сейчас пытаетесь достучаться до реального сайта `http:\\www.test.ru`, в то время как документ у вас локальный. Вместо urllib надо использовать открытие файла. Попробую накидать ваоиаент кода, когда буду за компом

Comment: @cauf Спасибо большое, надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: [Вот здесь](https://repl.it/@caufman/bs4fromfile) посмотри. Там же сверху можно нажать `Run` и посмотреть выполнение.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в вашем коде заключается в том, что метод `scrape()` не возвращает значение, таким образом, когда вы вызываете `Scraper(news).scrape()`, он просто выводит данные в консоль и ничего не возвращает.

Кроме того, когда вы вызываете метод `scrape()` в `f.write()`, он снова просто выводит данные в консоль, но не возвращает ничего. Вместо этого, вам нужно сохранить все найденные теги в переменную и записать их в файл.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Scraper:
    def __init__(self, site):
        self.site = site

    def scrape(self):
        r = urllib.request.urlopen(self.site)
        html = r.read()
        parser = "html.parser"
        sp = BeautifulSoup(html, parser)
        tags = []
        for tag in sp.find_all():
            tags.append(str(tag))
        return "\n".join(tags)

news = "https://news.google.com/topstories?hl=ru&gl=RU&ceid=RU:ru"
scraper = Scraper(news)
tags = scraper.scrape()
print(tags)

with open("news.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(tags)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка банальна - в функции `scrape` нет `return`, она ничего не возвращает.