# Не работает парсер на Python

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Если включить код, то будет работать пару секунд, при этом ничего не выводя, а потом выключится.
Код должен вывести **"Ссылка на видео - *ссылка*"**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parse_of_video():
    URL = 'https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending'
    HEADERS = {
        'User_Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36'
    }

    response = requests.get(URL, headers = HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'style-scope ytd-video-renderer')
    videos = []

    for item in items:
        videos.append({
            'link': item.find('a', class_ ='yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer').get('href')
            })

    for video in videos:
        print(f"Ссылка на видео - {video['link']}")

parse_of_video()
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1165952/При-парсинге-сайта-выводится-none возможный дубликат вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сайт наполняется динамически с помощью JavaScript. Средствами BeautifulSoup вы эту задачу не решите. **Вам нужен Selenium:**
[Как парсить html страничку с JavaScript в python 3?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/749943/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-html-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%81-javascript-%d0%b2-python-3)
[Парсинг динамических данных сайта на python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/803774/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python)

Answer (score 0):

Присоеденяюсь к ответу колеги. Однако, я бы посоветовал пользоваться **Scrappy**. Он будет немного быстрее нежели чем **Selenium**
Вот тут можно прочитать разницу между этими тремя инструментами:
[https://dev-gang.ru](https://dev-gang.ru/article/python-scrapy-selenium-beautiful-soup-czto-luczshe-dlja-parsinga-veb-saitov-rmv3n1q3us/)